# Change only the home URL in my WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website and the home page is configured to be the latest posts

What I want is that only the homepage URL that is, e.g. [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) redirects to subdomain.test.com and when the user needs to visit the older homepage will only access through test.com/home.

I need this because we will start a campaign in a landing page (subdomain.test.com) today.

But this is only for a few days, it is not a permanent change. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can redirect your website to sub domain ?

Comment: No, only the homepage, eg: test.com/ Others urls as test.com/contact or test.com/about will not redirect

Comment: So you can create a new page in WP where you can redirect to your sub domain ?

Comment: This can help you, hopefully.

Comment: But if i don't have any page configured in SETTINGS > READING? The option "Your latest posts" is checked

Comment: Okay so you can do this to make some changes in .htaccess file `RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://newsite.com.in/` add this in .htaccess file

Comment: Ok, but i need that  the older home be accessed through test.com/old_home. How can i do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163748/discussion-between-adittya-verma-and-eduardorph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a new page in WP where you can redirect to your sub domain.

**OR**

you can do this to make some changes in **.htaccess** file

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://newsite.com.in/
```

add this in **.htaccess** file